ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC : file download based on page's model and form
I've found various bits here and there on how to accomplish this but I hadn't found anything that put it all together.
I have two questions here:

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I don't want to go down the road of model binding for HTTP GET requests. I have A LOT of fields and I don't want to have to go through everything and add a [BindProperty(Name = "whatever", SupportsGet = true)] bunch of attributes for every field and every property I need to have provided to a GET.

How would I best handle errors with this on the Javascript side?  An an alert would be fine, but I'm interested in getting any error details to help diagnose why an error would occur. The controller example below omits error handling on the server side but it's present and functional. Should I even be worried about error handling in Javascript?


Page goal: Submit a form from an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC page that is using a model for the entire page including changes to the model made via the form with the end result being a file downloaded based on selections made and applied to the model.
Goal clarification:  The options a user chooses on this web page can be massive.  Enough that it can exceed the limit of what an Http GET would allow to be returned to the server.  Note this page may have 10 combo boxes/drop downs, that are all multi select fields.  Each combo box could have a few thousand selected options.  Don't ask to simplify.  It's part of the requirements.
Rough view example using _Layout for the body etc.:
@using MyNameSpace.ModelNameSpace
@model MyPagesViewModel;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = MyPagesViewModel._PageTitle; //public const string of _PageTitle
}

<div class="pageWrapper">
   <form id="MyForm" asp-controller="MyPageController" asp-action="SubmitForm" method="post">

       Customer Name: <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.CustomerName" />
       <button type="button" onclick="SubmitFormForFileDownload('MyPageController','CreateFileDownload','DownloadFile');">
       Export
       </button>
   </form>
</div>

Don't get stuck on the format above, it's just a form using a model as ASP.NET Core MVC does. I just hand typed it up as an example.
The goal was to submit the model and changes to the Form to be utilized when downloading a file.
The controller:
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyPageController/CreateFileDownload")]
public async Task <ActionResult> CreateFileDownload(MyPagesViewModelmodel)
{
   // Code to generate a file and store it on the server temporarily. Generating a file name in the process ...
   // Here I generate an excel file and save it to the server.
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullSavePath);
   return this.Ok(fi.Name);
}

public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    // Note you may need to add an argument for fileType if you have various file types.
    // This is an example for excel.
    string fileType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    string fullSavePath = Path.Combine(...your save directory path..., fileName);
    // load the file into a memory stream so I can delete it after.
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullSavePath));

    // delete the file to avoid retention issues.
    System.IO.File.Delete(fullSavePath);

    return File(stream, fileType, fileName);
}

Javascript to bring it all together - requires jQuery:
function SubmitFormForFileDownload(controllerName, generateFileAsyncActionName, fileDownloadActionName) {
    let formData = $(document.querySelector("form")).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/' + controllerName + '/' + generateFileAsyncActionName,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data: formData,
        success: function (fileNameResult) {
            console.log('successful file generation');
            window.location.href = '/' + controllerName + '/' + fileDownloadActionName + '?fileName=' + fileNameResult;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('unable to download the requested file.');
            console.log('unable to download the requested file.');
        }

    });
}


You shouldn't use any javascript, just let the browser handle it.  (any JS method would require creating a copy after the file is streamed to the front-end...) You also don't need to use two methods on the controller side, just combine those.

@browsermator, I hear what you're saying but I've not seen a way to create a file download without refreshing the page or by refreshing the page and returning your view of the page while at the same time having a file download occur.  If you have some examples or suggestions on how to do that I'd appreciate it.  Keep in mind, I need to submit the pages model as it has all the parameters used to generate the file download.  Note that total amount of options used to generate the file download may exceed a GET's size limit for returned parameters.

You don't need a GET, use a POST.  Give it a try.  You've already got the code written.  (Just bind the model...)

So as is you'd use something like   [BindProperty]
public string CustomerName { get; set; }   No need to pass in anything to the method.   So SubmitForm method of MyPageController can just be SubmitForm().  If you have a more complex model, you can just bind the whole model.  (plain old class object in the controller)  So something like   [BindProperty]
public YourClassName FormStuff { get; set; }  It'll bind accordingly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bindproperty-attribute

@browsermator, I mentioned BindProperty wasn't an option because [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] isn't valid on the class object.  The BindProperty presents a compile time error of "CS0592: Attribute 'BindProperty' is not valid on this declaration type.  It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations."

@browsermator, i just read your comment about not needing a get and using a Post.  I thought I had problems with returning a file result with a post but I've been down too many rabbit holes lately to be sure.  I'll give using a post a try.

@browsermator, yeah the POST doesn't work as it forces the page to move to the Controller and Action URL.  Where as the GET can return the file result without moving the page to the Controller and Action URL.

it's the reverse.  A GET update the URL bar... a POST will not. (parameters are sent in the body)  If it's processed via JS neither has to update the URL bar and the response goes to the JS script... which is why you'd need to then process the file there.  Just try the standard POST.

BTW, if the only data you need to create the file is already inside the form, you can probably create the file without ever hitting the server.  (Javascript can do that...)

I did test it.  And yes that's how GET and POST work.  That's not what I meant.  I meant that when I changed the download button to call a POST ActionResult which returns a file, the page was forced to move to the new Controller and Action URL as part of Routing I assume.  GET allows the result not to route the browser to the new URL with a GET ActionResult and returning a File.  If you have sample code that works please do add an answer to this.  Much appreciated!

my code would be the same as yours but without the onClick handler.  If the URL changes after a POST, then you have a redirect in a controller somewhere.  (Make sure you return File, as you do in your DownloadFile method.)

nope.  the code is exactly as shown above.  the onclick was updated to point at the new controller and action of the ActionResult returning a file.  Just isn't working.

you should remove the onclick.  You don't need any javascript here.  (just use ... though I think  would also work)

Oh wow.  Ok so that did work.  Thank you!  I had to also add the asp-controller and asp-action buttons but dang...  I guess I don't understand routing under the hood as well as I thought.  I'll put the final up as the answer.  thanks again!

So based on what @browsermator suggested, a much simpler solution was to change the button to a "submit" type button, add asp-controller and asp-action to the button, and have the action just return the file.  So much easier.  Thank you @browsemator!
View  - Just the button here...
<button type="submit" asp-controller="MyPageController" asp-action="DownloadFile"> 
    Download 
</button>

Controller
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyPageController/DownloadFile")]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    // This is an example for excel.
    string fileType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";


    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    
    ... Load your memory stream...

    //for me and how I had to load the memory stream, 
    //i needed to reset the stream to position 0.
    stream.Position = 0;

    //return the File object.  I had no idea the post wouldn't reload the page.
    return File(stream, fileType, fileName);
}

